# Error when trying to display data from oracle's table on console

Tags: java, oracle

I want to display database info on the console. Here is my main class code :

```
import java.sql.*;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/XE");
        Statement instruction = c.createStatement ();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM employees;";
        
        ResultSet r=instruction.executeQuery(query);
        
        while(r.next()) {
            System.out.println(r.getString("last_name"));
            
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

**EDIT** : I tried to add all the .jar file on my librarie and i have another error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules xmlparserv2.sans.jaxp.services and xmlparserv2 export package oracle.xml.xqxp.datamodel to module osdt.core

I used the driver jdbc11
I'm on windows 8.1,Eclipse IDE, JDK 17 (x64)

Answer (score 1):

Java classpath loader can load classes from jar/zip files and from unpacked directories.

On the othere hand you have a .tar.gz file.

Comment: Hello , i tried zip file, it's still not working

Comment: Which zip file did you try? Where did you get it?

Comment: The .tar.gz file contains many .jar files, I extracted them and recompressed them in .zip

Comment: i download the .tar.gz file from : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-21-4c-patched-downloads.html

Comment: What you downloaded is an installation archive, not the classpath library.

Comment: some of my classmates tested the same code and it works well for them, they downloaded and used the same file...

Comment: Why don't you ask your classmates then? You need to unpack this file, the jar files that you need are inside. You can also download the unzipped files separately from that page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem, just add all .jar files to the library remove the ; from

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
```